# Best Lamp Dimming Circuit?

Tags: schematics, light, dimmer, dimming, lighting

What's the best way to dim a lamp, and why? Also, which method is typically used in most typical residential dimmers? I originally thought it was as simple as wiring a potentiometer between the source and load, like this:
[image]
Or this:
[image]
Apparently not. I guess potentiometers are prone to overheating.

---

I notice a lot of schematics online simply add a transistor (BJT or FET):
[image]
[image]
Slightly different configuration:
[image]
I don't really understand how that's supposed to be any better, but it's relatively simple and I see it a lot.

---

Here's a (kind of confusing) [monostable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monostable) [555](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC) [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) circuit:
[image]

---

Here's a 240VAC pulsing circuit that uses a [diode bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_bridge) [rectifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier), capacitor and potentiometer:
[image]
Slightly more complicated:
[image]
Two capacitors:
[image]

---

And an unusual one with a transformer:
[image]

---

I'm sure there's probably more, but these are the schematics that I've simulated, and have on hand.

Comment: you've given this a lot of thought.  Most wall dimmers are just triacs with a couple discrete parts unless they are the digital ones with ramp dim, and pause with touch sequence for rapid off.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Yeah, I've been accused of not doing any research before asking (hastily written) questions, so I tried to be thorough. Plus I thought publishing them together might be helpful to someone. Thanks for writing in.

Comment: i find that n-chan mosfets to PWM a DC source dims LEDs the best

Answer (score 4):

In general for dimming a lamp following is applicable.

1. Make the amount of power going into the lamp variable
2. Prevent as much as possible the loss of power in the controller

In many domestic dimmers using mains this is done with a triac or IGBT controller.
[image]

The triac controller makes that an adjustable part of the incomming mains voltage is transfered to the lamp. Leading edge phase cutting.
An IBGT controller can operate with leading edge and trailing edge phase cutting.

Now if you replace the lamp with an LED device than the preferred methode of dimming is to rectify the incomming voltage and feed the DC voltage to the LED device in a chopped manner. This is called Pulse width modulation.

In some expensive dimmers one can preset the methode of dimming making such a dimmer suitable for Halogen lamps, LED Lamps with buildin electronics both trailing and leading edge modulation, CFL lamps and so on.

Comment: Cool. So is this applicable to (incandescent lamp) circuits with an AC power source only?

Comment: @HarrySvensson DIACs and TRIACs are new to me. They look like a pair of diodes back to back. I'll have to read up on them. So are there substitutes compatible with DC circuits?

Comment: The substitutes compatible with DC circuits are using transistor circuits. An IGBT controller is such a device. In transistor circuits the switching is fully controlled. Meaning that both on and off are controlled. A triac controller in combination with AC shuts off when the voltage passes zero or when the hold current becomes to low.

Comment: Whats the disadvantage of using a simple series resistor to dim ? What is the functionality of diac and triac and capacitor here? Don't know  ...simply asking

Comment: @MITURAJ You need to study the use of a diac and triac first. If you get stuck ask again in a question. The use of a series resistor works only with incandescent lamps and does produce wasted energy.

Comment: Hm what I know so far is they are used high power switching  !  Not really into power electronics. Anyway I will learn :-)